# Ejabberd: some questions about configurations

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have some questions about ejabberd server configurations:

1. How I can show private chat history on the Web Admin or/and export history    by specific date/time into the file? (I use Mysql for archive messages)
2. How I can configure MUC archive messages into mysql DB?
3. How I can export users passwords from encrypted mysql DB?
4. Why I can`t configure MUC rooms and users nicknames on the Web Admin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How I can show private chat history on the Web Admin or/and

Not possible.

> export history by specific date/time into the file? (I use Mysql for archive messages)

ejabberd doesn't provide any specific method. I guess you can use SQL queries for that.

> How I can configure MUC archive messages into mysql DB?

If you mean the archiving feature implemented in mod_mam, you can enable archiving in a room configuration (using a Jabber client, or enabling that option by default in ejabberd.yml)

> How I can export users passwords from encrypted mysql DB?

If the passwords are encrypted (using SCRAM by ejabberd), then they can't be decrypted.

> Why I can`t configure MUC rooms and users nicknames on the Web Admin?

Because the MUC pages in WebAdmin are very basic, only to view list of rooms and a few details, as you can see.

If you install **mod_shcommands** from ejabberd-contrib, that module provides a new page in WebAdmin to run ejabberd commands, so you can run commands like **change_room_option** and **muc_register_nick**